# HOW TO ADD ALTERNATIVE HTTP HEADERS TO MAGENTO 2

Tags: magento2.3, http-header

I wanna add custom header to the response.
l do like this [article](https://dev98.de/2017/01/02/how-to-add-alternative-http-headers-to-magento-2/)

but it does not work. I guest it about Magento version. I use Magento 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I tried this [How do I specify alternative headers for Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress.php](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-do-I-specify-alternative-headers-for-Magento-Framework-HTTP/td-p/40738) and it worked